# Maven Repository on Github not downloading transitive dependencies

Tags: android, maven, github, aar, transitive-dependency

I have created a maven repository and uploaded it to Github. When I add it as a dependency to a sample project, the gradle sync completes successfully. But when I try to run the app, it crashes with a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Link to repository: https://github.com/rjain90/sdk

Sample project code:

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
        realm_version = '5.8.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rjain90/sdk/master/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rjain90/sdk/master/" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext{
    lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
    android_support_version = '1.1.0-alpha01'
    legacy_support_version = '1.0.0'
    constraint_version = '1.1.3'

    retrofit_version = '2.4.0'
    dagger_version = '2.16'

    rxjava_version = '2.1.7'
    rxandroid_version = '2.0.1'
}
```

Module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

// Load keystore
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['ANDROID_KEYSTORE_LOCATION'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bowstring.godworld"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$android_support_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"

    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$legacy_support_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.cabfare.android:sdk:0.0.18@aar'
}
```

Comment: Why do you adding your "repository" (even, maybe not a repository) at the `repository` section? What you need may be a https://jitpack.io/.

Comment: @GenoChen I tried using Jitpack but ran into the same problem

Comment: What is the `NoClassDefError` generated for? For your library?

Comment: Besides, "the same problem" may even not precise: Maybe throwing for different place.

Comment: The error is the same in all cases: NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/internal/Platform

Comment: Is adding `implementation com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0` in your module `build.gradle`'s `dependencies` solve the issue?

Comment: After adding this, I get the same error but for the next dependency and so on

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub hosted, you can use https://jitpack.io as a Maven repository.

Add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` into the project `build.gradle`'s `allprojects -> repositories` block, then in your module `build.gradle`, add a dependency `implementation 'com.github.rjain90:sdk:0.0.17'`, for example.

However, your two releases are both [containing build errors](https://jitpack.io/com/github/rjain90/sdk/0.0.18/build.log). Solve them first.

Comment: I've removed the errors and tried again with Jitpack but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RishabhJain Did you "doesn't work" with `ERROR: Failed to resolve: Android-SDK-Core-Source:coresdk:unspecified`?

Comment: Yes and I tried to resolve it by using implementation 'com.github.rjain90:sdk:0.0.17@aar' but ran into the NoClassDefFoundError again

Comment: Yes. You can use `implementation 'com.github.rjain90:sdk:1.0'`, then you will found your SDK has the dependency `com.estimote:sdk:1.0.3` which depends on `Android-SDK-Core-Source:coresdk:unspecified` which throws the error. After you found where the `Android-SDK-Core-Source:coresdk:unspecified` is, the question is solved.

Comment: As of [my search](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK#introduction), "All the proximity monitoring features of this SDK have been deprecated and are no longer supported. Instead, we strongly recommend [Estimote Proximity SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-Proximity-SDK) for Android powered by Estimote Monitoring. ", which have no dependency problems as of the [Maven said](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.estimote/proximity-sdk/1.0.4).

Comment: Conclusion: At the `pom.xml` of your SDK, modify `com.estimote`'s `artifactId` from `sdk` to `proximity-sdk`, and use the newest version `1.0.4`, then let Jitpack rebuild your SDK, then you will probably successfully use your SDK in your project.

Comment: @RishabhJain The same error with what kind of detail? :-(